# Ubuntu Server 18.04 VM network and SSH issues from Ubuntu host

Tags: ssh

### What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu server 18.04.2 running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my laptop through Virtualbox. I want to ssh from my host computer into the VM server.

### Problems:

1. Ubuntu server 18.04.2 is showing `enp0s3` (no IP) and `lo` (IP 127.0.0.1) only and never shows any other connections no matter what I change in Virtualbox (or SSH side).
2. SSH establishes connections from host to guest but the connection inevitably fails.

### Setup and Versions:

1. Laptop OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
2. VM OS: Ubuntu server 18.04.2 (AMD64)
3. VM App: Virtualbox 5.2.18_Ubuntu r123745
4. Type of Network: WiFi

### Steps taken:

1. I've tried both NAT and Bridged connections through the steps in [Problems to connect to ubuntu server in a virtual machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953885/problems-to-connect-to-ubuntu-server-in-a-virtual-machine) and [Unable to ssh into Ubuntu VM running w/ a NAT ip address even w/ openssh-server installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224391/unable-to-ssh-into-ubuntu-vm-running-w-a-nat-ip-address-even-w-openssh-server). No positive results have occurred from these exercises.

**Case of NAT:**

[NAT Configuration in Virtualbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZYNq.png)

[NAT Port Forwarding Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMFF9.png)

**Case of Bridged Network:**

[Bridged connection Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw6fC.png)

**Note:** I don't use NAT and Bridged connection together, but exclusively.

2. I've also tried creating many private/public keys and signed certs for ssh- rsa, dsa, ecdsa etc on the host side using the instructions found in:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-creating_ssh_ca_certificate_signing-keys

https://superuser.com/questions/962888/what-does-key-load-public-no-such-file-or-directory-mean

https://superuser.com/questions/962888/what-does-key-load-public-no-such-file-or-directory-mean

3. I've left ufw inactive on VM server so as to not interfere with SSH for now

[UFW Firewall inactive on VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2C9I.png)

4. I've also changed some configs in the `ssh_config` file found in `/etc/ssh/`. In particular, I've changed the following configs:

```
    AllowTcpForwarding yes 
    GatewayPorts yes 
    PermitTunnel yes
```

I found some instructions about the above configs from: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sshd_config/#sec-Port-forwarding

None of the above steps I've taken have worked in a successful connection.

### Results Seen

When I try connecting from host laptop to the guest VM server, I see this in the guest VM side (in both NAT and Bridged):

[Network showing only enp0s3 and lo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdwdG.png)

I also see this on the host side when trying to connect:

[Host side SSH connection failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaxGa.png)

Comment: Have you tried to check the "Cable connected" checkbox in bridge or NAT adapter settings in virtualbox? In your screenshots its unchecked and that means your virtual ethernet cable is not plugged in. That works virtually the same as a hardware cable which also needs to be plugged in ;-)

Comment: @LienhartWoitok I tried that and seems like the connection has gone through. I was unaware of the mechanics of VMs. However, now I'm running up against an error related to too many encryption keys (rsa, dsa, ecdsa, etc). Do you know how to mitigate against this?

Comment: Can you share an error message? It might also help to add `-v` or `-vv` or even `-vvv` to the `ssh` command to get more verbose output and a more helpful error message. Please edit the information into your question.

Comment: I actually figured it out. I removed all the other encryption keys except rsa encryption key. After that I ssh'd into the VM server. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up a virtual network device you need to set the cable connected checkbox, otherwise the network device will be present but has no link.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I create the VM when I was using my `eno1` Ethernet connector.

Later I switched `eno1` to my router to get Internet and all LAN connections go through `eno2` instead (separation of network is more secure and much easier to manage).

A few days later I try my VPS and to my surprise I was getting a "No Route to Host".

Editing the settings of my VPSes and changing the connection to `eno2` resolved the issue.

*Side note:* I also have a strong firewall on `eno1` and `eno2` but I could not see anything being blocked when I tried to connect to my VPS. I use `-j LOG` for nearly any traffic that I block (arrogant hacker hits do not get logged, I just `-j DROP` them). My counters always go up on my Internet connection. However, the IP address never corresponded to my VPS. So I was pretty sure that the firewall wasn't the culprit.